# How can I change my plugins default page name in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently developing my first plugin in WordPress. Since it's a admin only plugin I only need admin panel things.

I've started creating the plugins menu in the left panel:

[image]

I've did this by defining the main page and a submenu page:

```
add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'edit', 'my-plugin', null, 'none', '58' );
add_submenu_page( 'my-plugin', 'Settings','Settings', 'edit', 'my-plugin-settings', [
    $this,
    'settings_page'
] );
```

Now I have a submenu with 2 entries. So far so good but I want to change the default submenu page of my plugin to `Dashboard` instead of the plugins name. I can't find anything in the docs so maybe someone of you knows the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the name of the main entry in the submenu - [`add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) only lets you set the page title and the main menu title.

What you can do instead is add a new item to the submenu for the main page. Add a new menu item using [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/), and use the same slug you used in `add_menu_page` as both the `$parent_slug` and `$menu_slug` parameters, e.g.

```
$plugin_base_slug = 'my-plugin';

add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'edit', $plugin_base_slug, null, 'none', '58' );

/* Replace the main menu page in submenu with the menu item "Dashboard" */
add_submenu_page( $plugin_base_slug, 'Dashboard', 'Dashboard', 'edit', $plugin_base_slug, null);

/* Add the rest of your submenu pages */
add_submenu_page( $plugin_base_slug, 'Settings','Settings', 'edit', 'my-plugin-settings', [
    $this,
    'settings_page'
] );
```

This will replace the main page menu in the submenu (i.e. the one called *My Plugin* in your example) with the new one you create in add_submenu_page (called *Dashboard* in this example).

Just make sure you use the same capability and function in your new submenu item so that it does the same thing as the main menu page.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Did that work for you or do you need more help?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Sorry for my late response but I needed to pause this project for some while. Now I'm continuing.